# Join two tables based on first available non-null value across multiple columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 different tables in BigQuery, one detailing a hierarchy for my organization, and the other table containing planning values for different entities. Before I explain further, here is how the tables look:

**Table A - Hierarchy**
This table is defined at a granular level for each warehouse. This is essentially a flattened hierarchy (Warehouse -> District -> City -> State -> Country)

| Country | State | City | District | Warehouse |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | S1 | CY1 | D1 | WH1 |
| C1 | S1 | CY1 | D1 | WH2 |
| C1 | S1 | CY1 | D2 | WH3 |
| C1 | S1 | CY1 | D2 | WH4 |
| C1 | S1 | CY2 | D3 | WH5 |
| C1 | S1 | CY2 | D3 | WH6 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Here is the other table:
**Table B - Planned Values**

| Frequency | PeriodStart | PeriodEnd | PlanAmount | Territory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MTD | 01/01/2022 | 01/31/2022 | 500 | WH1 |
| YTD | 01/01/2022 | 01/31/2022 | 790 | WH1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| MTD | 12/01/2022 | 12/31/2022 | 340 | WH1 |
| YTD | 12/01/2022 | 12/31/2022 | 1790 | WH1 |
| MTD | 01/01/2022 | 01/31/2022 | 1500 | D1 |
| YTD | 01/01/2022 | 01/31/2022 | 1800 | D1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| MTD | 12/01/2022 | 12/31/2022 | 1200 | D1 |
| YTD | 12/01/2022 | 12/31/2022 | 6600 | D1 |

I need to join Table A and Table B in the following manner to create a new table (**Table C**):

1. The driving table is Table A.
2. Table B contains planned values for warehouses, districts, cities etc. in Table B. However, it may contain these planned values defined at any level - sometimes at a warehouse level, and sometimes at only the country level.
3. For every warehouse in Table A, Table C must have the corresponding plan values from Table B *at the most granular level possible*. -- For example, Table B already has plan values for warehouse WH1, but **does not have** plan values for WH2. So, for WH1, Table C shows the plan values as defined within Table B. But for WH2, Table C has to show the district's (D1) plan values instead. If the district level value is not available, it has to skip to the next available level (leading all the way to the country level).

Is anyone able to help me with the logic to create this type of a join?

I am unable to think of the logical way to approach this since I am rather new to SQL. My approach was to create multiple left joins across each level and then use a coalesce, but I fear this will create duplicate values.

Comment: Table B has MTD and YTD entries. Which want shall be used? The table A shall extend for all months right? If shop opened currently, it will have entries for the past as well. If a shop closes, you will expect further sales values from the District. Join table B left to table A for all cases. Please show your work first. If this fails, because the data size is too large; we help with using windows function to solve it.

Comment: Both MTD and YTD are to be used. I have not come out with an approach for this as yet since the SQL seems to be too complex for my level of expertise. I would love to get some hints either in terms of a logical approach or SQL I can start off with and try.

Greatly appreciate all your help on this!

Comment: Also, at this time, I'm not worried about present or past values, nor the possibility of a shop closing.

Answer (score 0):

First I extract all dates from column `PeriodStart` in tableB. So there should be for each month a row with values. If you want to apply a row for several, please split them on a monthly base (unnest). The table A is written for each date in tableB.
For each entry in tableB the script will take the largest value per month and territory. If there are for this month are any match between `territory` and warehouse, the maximum of `PlanAmount` from these datasets in table B is taken. Otherwise (`ifnull`) it is checked for a match between `district` and `territory`.

```sql
with tblA as (select "C1" Country, "S1" State, "CY"|| (1+div(x,4)) City, "D"|| (1+div(x,2)) District, "WH"||x   Warehouse from unnest([1,2,3,4,5,6]) x),
tblB as (Select date("2022-01-01") PeriodStart, 500 PlanAmount, "WH1" Territory
UNION ALL SELECT date("2022-12-01"), 340, "WH1"
UNION ALL SELECT date("2022-12-01"), 1500, "D1"

),
months as (Select * from unnest(generate_date_array(  (Select min(PeriodStart) from tblB), (Select max(PeriodStart) from tblB),interval 1 month ))  as date_month ) ##generate all months in between
,
month_list as (Select distinct PeriodStart as date_month from tblB )

 
SELECT
date_month,country,state,city,District,
ifnull(ifnull(max(WHplan),max(Distplan)),max(Stateplane)) as plan 

from(
Select date_month, tblA.* ,
Wh.PlanAmount as WHplan,
Dist.PlanAmount as Distplan,
State.PlanAmount as Stateplane

from tblA,
#months # generate all months in between OR use:
month_list

left join  tblB WH
on tblA.Warehouse=WH.Territory and date_month=WH.PeriodStart

left join  tblB Dist
on tblA.District=Dist.Territory and date_month=Dist.PeriodStart

left join  tblB State
on tblA.District=State.Territory and date_month=State.PeriodStart
)
group by 1,2,3,4,5
```

Please tell if your dataset is too large for joins.